# Wordpress add widget to dashboard

Tags: wordpress, widget, shortcode, dashboard

i would like to add w custom widget at the dashboard of wp.
the problem is that i want to call a shortcode inside this widget.

The shortcode is "[my_rewards_log]" and this will display some points from all users.

Thanks for all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the do_shortcode function in the php code of the widget to have WordPress insert the shortcode result in the page:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_rewards_log]'); ?>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I already did this but it takes it as text at outpout. This print the shortcode as text